# How to pass net/http to other package

Tags: go

I use below code snippet for http server.

in main package:

```
http.HandleFunc("/aa", aahandler)
http.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(bbhandler.Wshandle))  
...
http.ListenAndServe()
```

the `bbhandler` is self-defined package.
Above code works.

Now I want to add a function `Register` in bbhandler.

```
Register() {
    http.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(Wshandle))  
    ... 
}
```

and main package code snippet will become as:

```
http.HandleFunc("/aa", aahandler)
bbhandler.Register()
...
http.ListenAndServe()
```

But above code seems not work, as main program will not handle `/echo`, it seems `bbhandler.Register` do not add `/echo` into main's `http`, So how can I pass main's http into `bbhandler` and add `/echo` handler function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Both invocations use `http.DefaultServeMux`, which is a package-level variable that is the very same object for both imports.

That said, it would be better design if you passed a `*http.ServeMux` into `Register` so the caller has control over where the handler gets added:

```
Register(mux *http.ServeMux) {
    mux.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(Wshandle))  
    ... 
}
```

And in `main`:

```
http.HandleFunc("/aa", aahandler)
bbhandler.Register(http.DefaultServeMux)
...
http.ListenAndServe()
```